# FIP Deployment Error

Tags: tooltwist

We are deploying on one of our server and we have below error.

ERROR: tooltwist.fip.FipException Unknown response from server: 500: Internal Server Error
Exception: tooltwist.fip.FipException: tooltwist.fip.FipException: Unknown response from server: 500: Internal Server Error

Looking at the FIP log, it shows:

Error installing batch: tooltwist.fip.FipException: Pre-commit command failed: protected/pre_commit.sh
tooltwist.fip.FipException: Pre-commit command failed: protected/pre_commit.sh
        at tooltwist.fip.FipServer_updateExecuter.commitTransaction(FipServer_updateExecuter.java:309)
        at tooltwist.fip.FipServer_updateExecuter.prepareUpdates_1_3(FipServer_updateExecuter.java:250)
        at tooltwist.fip.FipServer_updateExecuter.executeUpdates(FipServer_updateExecuter.java:142)
        at tooltwist.fip.FipServer.destination_installBatchOfFiles(FipServer.java:199)
        at tooltwist.fip.jetty.InstallBatchServlet.doPost(InstallBatchServlet.java:134)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:931)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:867)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:775)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:437)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Any idea about the error?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions:
1. Does the pre_commit.sh shell script exist on the server.
2. Does it have +x permissions?

If FIP was installed using the normal way, it should not cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The fipserver initially saves files it receives on the destination server, but into temporary locations. Once all of the files have been received and saved it runs a three step process to complete the installation:

> ```
>    1. Run a script named protected/pre-commit.sh. The normal operation of this script is to shut down the web server.
>    2. For each new file:
>        a) move any existing file to .fip-rollback-xxxxxx/filename.
>        b) move the new file from it's temporary location to the correct location.
>    3. Run a script named protected/post-commit.sh. This most commonly restarts the server.
> ```

The pre and post commit scripts are user provided. They should should normally exit with a status of zero, as any other status indicates that an error has occurred.

As suggested in the previous answer, check that these scripts exist, and that they are executable. If this fails to solve your problem, insert debug into the scripts to determine where and why they are failing.

Comment: Actually I tried all those suggestion, before asking the question, the pre-commit.sh does not do anything except changing directory...  
    
    ls -l  
    total 16  
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 widgetti widgetti 880 Oct  8 21:41 post_commit.sh  
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 widgetti widgetti 190 Oct  8 21:39 pre_commit.sh  
    
    $ cat pre_commit.sh   
    #  
    # Check we have a few required directories, that might not hve been created because they are empty.  
    #  
    dir=`dirname $0`  
    
    cd /home/widgetti/server/tomcat/bin  
    #./shutdown.sh  
    
    exit 0

Comment: The only other reason could be that FIP was being run as a different user to widgetti ?  and it has no execute permissions?